# Stop recompiling usercontrols without code behind

Tags: c#, .net, iis, aspx-user-control, temporary-asp.net-files

I have a CMS created in asp.net FrameWork 4.72. hosted on an IIS 8.5

The content is rendered by loading Usercontrols without Codebehind(example below) so I without updating bin files can make changes to content

My Issue is that when I make a change to a single Usercontrols it seems like IIS recompiles a lot other usercontrols(updating files in %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64]<vernum>\Temporary ASP.NET Files folder). It sometimes takes 2-3 minutes before site is up running again.

I looked into disabling fcnMode but that didnt work

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="false" Inherits="Comito.CMS.FrontEndShared.Templates.BaseUserControl" %>
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var basePage = (Comito.CMS.FrontEndShared.Templates.BasePage)Page;
    if (basePage.Document != null)
    {
        Comito.CMS.Domain.Entity.Document.Document Document = basePage.Document;    
        LitTitle.Text = Document.Title;      
    }
}
</script>
<asp:Literal id="LitTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Comment: I found this document, is it helpful for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/code-behind-class-files

Comment: No, thats about code-behind controls. Im using usercontrols with inline code

Comment: For us, it is not possible to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.